# Image behind the post's title

Tags: posts, images, title

I'm trying to find question how to change or at least resize annoying image behind post's title, see attachment:

[image: annoing image]

You can see it on address: http://promisingcoins.com/electroneum_part1/

I use theme Structural. How can I change that stupid picture? I spent hours browsing all options in wordpress, looking through internet,... It isn't header and it doesn't occur on the main page, but after clicking on any post it will appear.

Thanks a lot for any advice.

Comment: Feel free to ask me any question if you don't fully understand the question :-)

Comment: On a side note, from an editor's standpoint: consider changing "Master’s degree in Finance and Investment management provides me a great theoretical background. On the other hand, I work as a financial analyst what gives me practical experience." to "A master’s degree in Finance and Investment Management provides me with a great theoretical background. I also work as a financial analyst, which gives me practical experience." Also, English uses "mining" rather than „mining“.

Comment: I really appreciate your help and I've changed it on the page "About me", thank you. Quotation marks have been changed because of my Word 2016 (I haven't changed language from my native language).

Comment: You're very welcome. Now, if you want to, you can change the quotes by directly specifying the unicode characters. Try changing your link tag to this: `<a href="http://promisingcoins.com/electroneum_part1/">Electroneum – cell phone &#x201c;mining&#x201d;</a>`. For more information, have a look at [this](https://www.w3schools.com/charsets/ref_utf_punctuation.asp) and related reference tables. You can add any character to an HTML string by preceding its UTF-8 hex value with `&#x` and following it with `;`. One more example that might interest you: entering `&#x20bf;` will give you this: ₿.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The image you are referring to is set via your themes `style.css` file and not via the WordPress admin or in your theme options. You can find the file here:

`http://promisingcoins.com/wp-content/themes/structural/style.css`

Here is the CSS that is used for this section (line #1305):

```
.breadcrumb {
    background: url(images/breadcrumb.png);
    position: relative;
    text-align: center;
    padding: 60px 0px;
    margin-top: 0;
    text-transform: uppercase;
}
```

The image itself (http://promisingcoins.com/wp-content/themes/structural/images/breadcrumb.png) is a little strange as it only has 2 thirds of the actual image containing the texture/effect so can't really be resized easily to fill the full width of the site using CSS.

In order to change the image, I would strongly recommend using a [child theme](https://codex.wordpress.org/Child_Themes) or adding CSS via your theme options (if there is an option to add custom CSS) rather than editing your theme files directly, to add the following CSS code to your child themes style.css file or custom CSS in your theme options:

```
.breadcrumb {
        background: url(path-to-new-background-image.png);
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, I really appreciate your answer as it saved my time (I guess, at least another hour!)

Comment: Great news! If my answer helped, would you mind clicking on the tick next to my answer to accept it please?

Comment: Yes, of course!